# pronunciation of 'Via Galactea'

Tags: pronunciation

How to pronounce 'Via Galactea'? Could you write it in international phonetic alphabet?

Answer (score 5):

So first of all, *galactea* isn't native Latin (the *galact-* root is Greek, but I'd expect the Greek form to be something like *galactica*). It sounds like you're trying to translate "Milky Way"; the Latin for that would be *[via] lactea*.

Latin's been pronounced a LOT of different ways. No matter how you say it, there's sure to be someone who considers it correct. But since you mention being in Asia, most likely you want Reconstructed Classical or Ecclesiastic (church) pronunciation.

Reconstructed would be something like `/ˈwia ˈlaktea/`.
Ecclesiastic would be closer to `/ˈvia ˈlaktea/`.

Comment: Then, is 'Via Galactea' an ancient Greek word? Oh no

Comment: The Greek for Milky Way is *galaxias* (which gives our word *galaxy*). *Galactea* doesn't seem to be a Latin word -- at least, it's not in L&S.

Comment: The Greek name for the Milky Way is γαλαξίας κύκλος.

Comment: In Italian it is vía láttea, with the stress on the same syllables as in Latin.

Comment: @fdb Thanks! Altered the answer accordingly.

Comment: @fdb Note that the *via lactea* is also called the *circulus lacteus*, nearer from the Greek…